# Using knocking and knock

Tags: grammar

> For a Halloween event, I dressed up as a student, **knocked** on my teacher's doors, and received extra homework.

Can this sentence be rewritten using *knocking*? Is the following grammatically correct and used?

> I dressed up as student, **knocking** on my teacher's doors, he gave me extra homework.

Under what circumstances do we use *knocking*? How can we phrase it?

Comment: For a Halloween event I dressed up as a student; I found though, that knocking on my teacher's doors only resulted in receiving extra homework. Leave it to a teacher to opt for the "Trick".

Comment: can i also write: "I dressed up as a student, knocked on my teacher's doors, then the teacher gave me extra homework?

Comment: here `but` would be more appropriate than `then`.

Comment: It should be either _teacher's door_, or _teachers' doors_, but not _teacher's doors_ – not unless you knocked at both the front door and the back door of the same house.

Comment: Did you knock while dressing? At the same time? If not, keep the sequence: _dressed, then knocked_. Not _dressed, [while] knocking_.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to get "knocking" into the verbiage, but you need to be careful about how you mix the past tense (*dressed up as*) with the participle (*knocking*). Here are two ways I might do it:

> For Halloween, I dressed as a student. After knocking on my teacher's door, he gave me extra homework.
>
> For Halloween, I dressed as a student. I went knocking on doors – only to get extra homework.

I think these work because of the words *after, gave,* and *went*, which clearly put the context in the past.

The sentence sounds like it's supposed to be a quip with a punchline. The kid actually doesn't wear a costume ("dressing as a student" simply means he's wearing his day-to-day clothing). He thought he was being clever by calling this so-called costume "dressed as a student," but the joke was on him when he got homework instead of candy. That's why I've punctuated with the dash in my second option, to set up the pause for the punchline. If there was no joke, there would be no dash:

> For Halloween, I dressed as a student. I went knocking on doors and got a ton of candy.

---

As a footnote, there's nothing wrong with "dressed up as," but I opted to use the more concise "dressed as." Either one makes sense, and they are both valid in this context.

Comment: Hi, is this sentence grammatically correct? "I dressed  as a student, knocked on my teacher's door, (and) then the teacher gave me extra homework?" Can I insert the "and" or does that force parallelism?

Comment: The sentence you've asked about here is just fine: _I dressed as a student, knocked on my teacher's door, and then the teacher gave me extra homework._ I prefer the option with the "and"; if any word could be removed, I'd nominate the "then": I dressed as a student, knocked on my teacher's door, and the teacher gave me extra homework. The "then" is implied because the sentence reads like a sequence of events.

Answer (score 0):

**knocking** would be used in a sentence like

> For a Halloween event I dressed up as a student; knocking on my teacher's doors only got me more homework.

Comment: Somehow, I think your sentence is problematic.

Comment: How so?  it's not the best possible sentence, I do accept. But it's the only way to use "knocking" properly. A possible edit is "but" instead of "so"...

Comment: I couldn't tell exactly why I think it's problematic. But I think at least this use of *so* is. I'm not even sure how to interpret this *so*. It's not the same to *so do I* or *Who says so?*. It's not *I'm so in love*. It's not *It's more expensive to travel on Friday, so I'll leave on Thursday*. It's not *She's staying here for six months so that she can perfect her English*.

Comment: "so" as in "as a result of which"....

Comment: That's one thing I thought it is problematic, because I couldn't see how *knocking ...* could be a result of *I dressed up ...*.

Comment: Getting homework was a result of dressing up and knocking.

Comment: Yes but *knocking on my teacher's doors only got me more homework* is not the result of *dressing up*.

Comment: Yes, it is. Kids get candy on Halloween, and handing out homework instead of candy was a sarcastic response from the teacher because of the student outfit.

Comment: Okay, let me make this clear. First, I didn't say that your sentence is *wrong*. But I did (and do) think that it's problematic. For one thing, to make it be cause-and-result, the kid must dress up like that, expecting to knock the door and get more homework. If the kid dressed up like that, and knocked the door just to surprise that she got more homework instead (of candies), I wouldn't say *dressing up* is the cause of the result. I would say that it's more like both *dressing up* and *knocking on the door* are the causes of the result (of getting more homework).

Comment: Knocking on the door is but obvious. Had the kid dressed up as a wizard/witch, or some monster, he _would have received candy_ and not homework. The outcome would have been different despite the knocking, implying that the knocking had nothing to do with the actual reason the kid got homework. The teacher was being smart, and as a joke he gave homework to the trick-or-treat-er dressed as a student. So what really did the trick (pun intended) was the _dressing as student part_.

Comment: The sentence does have a few problems: (1) there's the "teacher's doors" problem – which I just explained in a comment to the O.P. (2) You can dress up for a Halloween _event_, but you wouldn't go knocking on doors – an "event" is more like a private party. For trick-or-treating, you simply dress up "for Halloween." (3) I think the word "so" reads awkward as a conjunction in this context; it sounds "forced." Here's how I'd recommend saying it: **I dressed up as a student for Halloween; knocking on my teacher's door only got me more homework.**

Comment: This correction sounds much better. Thanks. That is similar to what I was trying to drive to.

Comment: Ashish: Feel free to make an edit and use what I wrote.